# How to merge two files in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of systems, each system has two servers: database1 server(db1), and database2 server(db2). I created two text files db1_list and db2_list as below:

db1_list:

```
db1-env1: 10.8
db1-env2: 10.7
db1-env3: 10.7
db1-env4: 10.8
...
db1-envX: 10.6.2
```

db2_list:

```
db2-env1: 10.8
db2-env3: 10.7
db2-env2: 10.7
db2-envX: 10.6.2
...
db2-env4: 10.8
```

Each file has the server name, and the database version. The two files are not necessarily in the same order.

I want to create a new file that "merges" those two files and has the output like this:

```
db1-env1: 10.8, db2-env1: 10.8
db1-env2: 10.7, db2-env2: 10.7
db1-env3: 10.7, db2-env3: 10.7
db1-env4: 10.8, db2-env4: 10.8
......
db1-envX: 10.6.2, db2-envX: 10.6.2
```

How can I do that in Ansible?

Comment: This question is not seeking a [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Quoting: `"find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".  Instead, it's [a practical, answerable problem unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Quoting: "... merge two files, not in the same order." The accepted answer provides this algorithm (create index, sort, merge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the files

```yaml
shell> cat db1_dict.yml
db1-env1: 10.8
db1-env2: 10.7
db1-env3: 10.7
db1-env4: 10.8
db1-envX: 10.6.2
```

```yaml
shell> cat db2_dict.yml
db2-env1: 10.8
db2-env3: 10.7
db2-env2: 10.7
db2-envX: 10.6.2
db2-env4: 10.8
```

Declare the list of the dictionaries and the pattern of the names

```yaml
db: [db1_dict, db2_dict]
db_name_regex: 'db\d+-env(.*)'
```

Read the dictionaries from the files

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}.yml"
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ db }}"
```

---

Optionally, test the sanity of the names

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: "{{ db_names is all }}"
        fail_msg: "The names in {{ item }}.yml do not match {{ db_name_regex }}"
      loop: "{{ db }}"
      vars:
        db_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
        db_names: "{{ db_dict.keys()|map('regex_search', db_name_regex)|list }}"
      when: sanity_names|d(false)|bool
```

---

Create the indexed list

```yaml
  db_names_str: |
    {% for d in db %}
    {% for k,v in lookup('vars', d).items() %}
    - index: "{{ k|regex_replace(db_name_regex, '\1') }}"
      name: {{ k }}
      version: {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  db_names: "{{ db_names_str|from_yaml|sort(attribute='index') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  db_names:
    - {index: '1', name: db1-env1, version: 10.8}
    - {index: '1', name: db2-env1, version: 10.8}
    - {index: '2', name: db1-env2, version: 10.7}
    - {index: '2', name: db2-env2, version: 10.7}
    - {index: '3', name: db1-env3, version: 10.7}
    - {index: '3', name: db2-env3, version: 10.7}
    - {index: '4', name: db1-env4, version: 10.8}
    - {index: '4', name: db2-env4, version: 10.8}
    - {index: X, name: db1-envX, version: 10.6.2}
    - {index: X, name: db2-envX, version: 10.6.2}
```

Write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ db_names_path }}"
        content: |
          {% for i in db_names|groupby('index') %}
          {% for j in i.1 %}
          {{ j.name }}: {{ j.version }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/db_names.csv 
db1-env1: 10.8, db2-env1: 10.8
db1-env2: 10.7, db2-env2: 10.7
db1-env3: 10.7, db2-env3: 10.7
db1-env4: 10.8, db2-env4: 10.8
db1-envX: 10.6.2, db2-envX: 10.6.2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    db: [db1_dict, db2_dict]
    db_name_regex: 'db\d+-env(.*)'
    db_names_path: /tmp/db_names.csv

    db_names_str: |
      {% for d in db %}
      {% for k,v in lookup('vars', d).items() %}
      - index: "{{ k|regex_replace(db_name_regex, '\1') }}"
        name: {{ k }}
        version: {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    db_names: "{{ db_names_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}.yml"
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ db }}"

    - assert:
        that: "{{ db_names is all }}"
        fail_msg: "The names in {{ item }}.yml do not match {{ db_name_regex }}"
      loop: "{{ db }}"
      vars:
        db_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
        db_names: "{{ db_dict.keys()|map('regex_search', db_name_regex)|list }}"
      when: sanity_names|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: db_names|to_yaml

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ db_names_path }}"
        content: |
          {% for i in db_names|groupby('index') %}
          {% for j in i.1 %}
          {{ j.name }}: {{ j.version }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks Vladimir Botka !!!!!